# Prove that if $~x,~y \in \mathbb R~$, $~f(x)=f(y)~$ and $~x=y~$. (Proof verification)

Tags: functions, proof-verification

$~f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R~$ is a function on $~\mathbb R~$, and $~\{f_z\}~$ is a sequence of real valued functions on $~\mathbb R~$ defined by $~f_1(x)=f(x), ~x  \in \mathbb R ~$ and $~f_{z+1}=f[f_z(x)] ,~x ~\in \mathbb R ,~~~ z=1,2,3,4,\cdots~$

Assume there exists a positive integer $~z_0~$ such that $~f_{z_0}(x)=x       \forall x \in \mathbb R ~$.

Prove that the function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is injective.

Proof:
Suppose f(x)=f(y), then $f_z$(x)=$f_z$(y) for every z. Thus, $f_{z_0}$(x)=$f_{z_0}$(y).

$f_{z_0}$(x)=x=y=$f_{z_0}$(y)

Now I also have a proof by contradiction.

Assume $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is not injective. This implies that there exists x,y in R such that x  != y (x doesn't equal y), f(x)=f(y) which then implies $f_z$(x) = $f_z$(y) for all n.

However, there exists the positive integer $z_0$ such that $f_{z_0}$(x)=x for all x in R.

x=$f_{z_0}$(x)=$f_{z_0}$(y)=y

which contradicts our assumption.

Q.E.D.

Comment: What do you want to prove? Can you edit your question and write a statement please?

Comment: @OlivierRoche I'm trying to prove f:R-->R is injective.

Comment: Please edit your question to typeset the mathematics with [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), in order to make the question more readable.

Comment: @Mathissohardlmao
Both proofs are fine. They are essentially the same, so I would avoid the proof by contradiction here.

Comment: "n" is undefined in your second proof attempt. Also, don't write things like "$f_{z_0}(x) = x ∀x∈\mathbb{R}$"; it's syntactically malformed. The proper syntax for such logical symbols is with the quantifier in front: "$∀x∈\mathbb{R}\ ( f_{z_0}(x) )$". Also, normally we write a chain of equalities where each equality in the chain is easily deduced, to justify the equality between the first and last in the chain, so instead of writing "$f_{z_0}(x) = x = y = f_{z_0}(y)$" you should have written "$x = f_{z_0}(x) = f_{z_0}(y) = y$".